# Show that number $n^2$ after division by $8$ can have remains only $0, 1$ or $4$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

Show that number $n^2$ after division by $8$ can have remains only $0, 1$ or $4$

What is the solution?

Comment: While all the answers below are correct, I'd point you to @zongxiangyi's answer, as it is really explains how to do problems like this in general. If you want to know possible values of $n^2$, you generally want to to look at numbers of the form $n = ak+r$ where $a$ is the smallest number possible so that $n$ divides $a^2$, $k$ is a genuine variable, and $r$ ranges from 0 to $a-1$. For example, if you'd wanted to know about $n^2$ on division by 32, you'd use $a = 8$, or if you wanted $n^2$ on division by 12 you'd use $a=6$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if $$n\equiv 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 \mod 8$$ then we get
$$n^2\equiv 0,1,4,1,0,1,4,1 \mod 8$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if you take squares in the set $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ and take the results **modulo $8$**, you get $\{0,1,4,1,0,1,4,1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $n=4k$, $n^2=(4k)^2=16k^2$, so after division by 8, the remainder is 0.

If $n=4k+1$, $n^2=(4k+1)^2=16k^2+8k+1$, so after division by 8, the remainder is 1.

If $n=4k+2$, $n^2=(4k+2)^2=16k^2+16k+4$, so after division by 8, the remainder is 4.

If $n=4k+3$, $n^2=(4k+3)^2=16k^2+24k+8+1$, so after division by 8, the remainder is 1.

Finally, that number n^2 after division by 8 can have remains only 0, 1 or 4.